# unsupported_grant_type in Web Api 2

Tags: ajax, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

i am beginner in Web Api and implementing authorization and authentication  but getting some error as i mentioned below:

I am getting this error while getting token from webApi

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":\"unsupported_grant_type\"}","responseJSON":{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

This is my jQuery code to make request for token

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var details = "{'grant_type':'password', 'username': '" + $("#UserName").val() + "', 'password': '" + $("#Password").val() + "' }";
        console.log(details);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            data: details,
            url: "http://localhost:59926/token",
            success: function (data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); },
            error: function (data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `contentType` should be `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` should be like query string, not JSON object. And you should encode params if need

```
data: 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(user.username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(user.password) + '&grant_type=password'
```

Answer (score -1):

`contentType` is wrong. It should be `application/json`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var details = "{'grant_type':'password', 'username': '" + $("#UserName").val() + "', 'password': '" + $("#Password").val() + "' }";
        console.log(details);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: details,
            url: "http://localhost:59926/token",
            success: function (data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); },
            error: function (data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); }
        });
    });
```

Comment: but i am getting the same error:   `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":\"unsupported_grant_type\"}","responseJSON":{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}`

Comment: post your webapi code as well and how you are trying to implement authentication